# Java JSP custom tag for nested tree structure.

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to create my custom Java JSP tags for tree structure such as:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Root</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Node</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Node</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Node</a></li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Node</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Node</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Node</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

In JSP file an XML should looks like:

```
<lib:treeview>
    <lib:treenode path="/some/path.do" label="Root">
    <lib:treenode path="/some/path.do" label="NodeLabel"/>
    <lib:treenode path="/some/path.do" label="NodeLabel"/>
    <lib:treenode path="/some/path.do" label="NodeLabel"/>
    </lib:node>
</lib:treeview>
```

Did somebody implement nested structures like this one? What classes are better to use? Maybe somebody has some useful links? Help, please :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, something like this should work:

treeview.tag:

```
<%@ tag description="treeview" %>
<ul>
    <jsp:doBody />
</ul>
```

treenode.tag:

```
<%@ tag description="treenode" %>
<%@ attribute name="label" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="path" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<li>
    <a href="${path}">${label}</a>
    <jsp:doBody />
</li>
```

test.jsp:

```
<lib:treeview>
    <lib:treenode label="root" path="#">
        <lib:treeview>
            <lib:treenode label="node" path="#">
            <lib:treenode label="node" path="#">
            <lib:treenode label="node" path="#">
        </lib:treeview>
    </lib:treenode>
</lib:treeview>
```

output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">root</a>
        <ul>
            <a href="#">node</a>
            <a href="#">node</a>
            <a href="#">node</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSP tree is simple one. You can enhance. It has checkboxes as well. The complete source code and Read Me file will guide you. I have wrote this in my free time. Bye

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsptree-simple/